# Using mod operator in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logic

Items:

1 2 3 **4** 5 6 7 **8** 9 10 11 **12** 13 14 15 **16** 17 18

---

Repeater control I want to place class on highlighted item number.

so ... I have done following code.

```
if ((DL_NewProducts.Items.Count) % 3 == 0)
{
    var libox = e.Item.FindControl("libox") as HtmlGenericControl;
    if (libox != null)
        libox.Attributes["class"] = "last";
}
```

Here is problem that in first iteration it find three items, mod work fine and it place class on 4th item but in second iteration it come again on 6th item and place class on 7th item while I want it to place it on 8th what will be correct logic for it..

Comment: I don't see any iteration. Perhaps you could post the loop that encompasses the if?

Comment: you need the mod of 4 not three

Comment: Besides the other good advice here, I would check to see what the precedence of evaluation is on the % and the ==.

Comment: @Liviu - Iteration is implicit, done by the `Repeater` web control. There is no explicit loop that you can see.

Comment: If you're doing this in a repeater wouldn't you want to use the `ItemIndex` not `DL_NewProducts.Items.Count`?? There might be more to it than what is posted so it might not be a problem.

Comment: IMPORTANT: % is often called wrongly called the mod operator but it is actually the remainder operator.  -3 mod 5 == 2.  -3 % 5 == -3.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question isn't completely clear - you have marked the sequence 4, 8, 12, ... in bold but appear to actually want the numbers in the sequence 3, 7, 11... to pass the test.

So I *think* you're looking for the expression:

```
DL_NewProducts.Items.Count % 4 == 3
```

But it's hard to tell since it isn't clear if those numbers at the top represent counts, zero-based indices or one-based indices. If you can clarify exactly what they represent and how they relate to the collection's count, we might be able to provide more appropriate answers.

Comment: SOF says the 6th item is selected and the 7th item decorated when the 8th was wanted so I suspect mod 4 is right but there is some sort of offset issue (starting from 0 instead of 1) - I can't see where the iteration is though. I've never used a repeater so maybe it's obvious to others.

Comment: @Russell: It's hard to tell. If the OP wants to *place it* on the 8th, he/she probably wants the test to pass for `7` (going by the offset of `1` for the previous part of that sentence).

Comment: @Russell, my guess is that the OP is in an `ItemDataBound` or `ItemCreated` event, and the `.Count` property is reflective of the number of items currently bound, which would be the previous x items. So if he's dealing with Item 8 right now, Count would reflect 7.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `(DL_NewProducts.Items.Count % 4) == 0`.

Comment: It's more likely that Ani is correct. Count 3 is Item 4, Count 7 is Item 8, etc.

Comment: Maybe even `((DL_NewProducts.Items.Count + 1) % 4) == 0` for cases like OP is using.